# Cloud Composer - How to enable private IP environment?

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to enable the private IP environment for cloud composer.

However, I'm getting into IP issues, but I don't know how to solve them in GCP:

> Http error status code: 400 Http error message: BAD REQUEST Additional
>   errors:
>   {"ResourceType":"qba864c4814984c15-tp/compute-address-v1-api:globalAddresses","ResourceErrorCode":"UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION","ResourceErrorMessage":"Requested
>   range conflicts with other resources: The provided IP range overlaps
>   with reserved range for auto subnetwork."}

It used to work in a default environment, where I created a cloud NAT with a IP address and all of the request when to the cloud NAT.

Now when I tried to re-create the environment, it started saying that the IP ranges overlaps even though there's no change in my GCP project.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the IP ranges you're trying to configure the environment with?

Comment: @hexacyanide Everything is just default. With Pod IP address set as create new secondary range.